# Transfer content between local table to remote table

Tags: sql-server

I've got 2 SQL instances that I need to transfer data between.
Both instances have a database that is essentially the same, the intent is to transfer data from the Production used one to the other which will act as an archive of sorts (this is to keep the amount of records in the one applications point to at a minimum for efficiency).

The source database is used very heavily, with inserts coming in approx. every 2-3 seconds.
My original thought was to do something like the below so it could be a single transaction, however it would appear this can't be done with a remote table (via linked server)

```
With X as (
select col1, col2, col3 from SRCDB.table where <conditions>
) Delete from X
Output deleted.col1, deleted.col2, deleted.col3 INTO destDB.table
```

Comment: Is this going to be onetime load you are looking for? Or you need this as incremental after one time full load?

Comment: @SivaDasari Intent is to have this run nightly, archiving off data that isn't required for the following day. I've just updated the sample code with a where clause as this wasn't obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure about the size of the table, but have you looked for nightly [bcp export and import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/aa337544(v=sql.105)) as an option.
You could run delete on source separately by batching.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [tempdb].[dbo].sourceTable
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [tempdb].[dbo].staging_SourceTable
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [tempdb].[dbo].targetTable
GO

--Your source table
CREATE TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].sourceTable(id int identity(1,1) Primary Key, fname char(10), lname char(10), createddate datetime2(0) default getdate())
GO
INSERT INTO [tempdb].[dbo].sourceTable(fName, lName) VALUES ('fName1','lName1')
INSERT INTO [tempdb].[dbo].sourceTable(fName, lName) VALUES ('fName2','lName2')
INSERT INTO [tempdb].[dbo].sourceTable(fName, lName) VALUES ('fName3','lName3')
GO

--Stage data before BCP out, so you can use this to delete from source
CREATE TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].staging_SourceTable(id int)
GO
INSERT INTO [tempdb].[dbo].staging_SourceTable
SELECT ID --Choose primary key or any unique column
FROM [tempdb].[dbo].sourceTable 

--BCP out command, I’m using staging table in my query
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 
'bcp "SELECT s.id, s.fname, s.lname, s.createddate FROM [tempdb].[dbo].sourceTable s JOIN [tempdb].[dbo].staging_SourceTable stg on s.id = stg.id" queryout C:\temp\outputFile.bcp -S localhost -c -T -b 1000'

--Create schema on target instance
CREATE TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].targetTable(id int, fname char(10), lname char(10), createddate datetime2(0))
GO

--BCP in command
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 
'bcp [tempdb].dbo.targetTable in C:\temp\outputFile.bcp -S localhost -c -T -b 1000'

--At this point you are safe to delete from source
WHILE 1 = 1
 BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1000 ID 
    INTO #temp 
    FROM tempdb.dbo.staging_SourceTable

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BREAK

    DELETE s
    FROM tempdb.dbo.sourceTable s
    JOIN #temp t on s.id = t.id

    DELETE stg
    FROM tempdb.dbo.staging_SourceTable stg
    JOIN #temp t on stg.id = t.id
    
    DROP TABLE #temp

 END
```

Comment: Hey Siva,
The issue is being able to effectively identify which records have been archived to then remove them from the source (given the frequent updates occurring on the database).

Comment: @Sir_Edward I have added some simulated code to my answer, see if that helps. Let me know otherwise.